# how to manage hello.gram for conversation using sphinx and freetts in java

Tags: java, speech-recognition, grammar, speech-to-text, cmusphinx

I am developing small voice based interaction tool using sphinx (Speech to Text) and FreeTTS(Text to Speech) in java.

for eg : FreeTTS gives voice command like Name : user will reply his name and age and place.everything is static.

How to write hello.gram in sphinx to achieve this

```
public<greet>=[<name>] [<age>] [<place>];
<name> = john | max;
<age> = ten | nine ;
<place> = France | Spain;
```

Voice command : What is your name
my reply : Max

Observation : Max ten

Voice command : what is your age
my reply : nine

Observation : nine France

I want only names should be observed when i say name.its highly intermittent too :(

Thanks in advance.

## modified based on Alexander's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code to avoid it .

```
public <name> = john | max;
public <age> = ten | nine ;
public <place> = France | Spain;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no *magical* method to do what you want. You have to specify all phrases that you want to be recognized in your grammar. The only thing I can recommend is to factorize some rules, e.g. numbers:

<digits> = one | two | three | four ;
   <decades> = twenty | thirty | forty ;
   <numto44> = <decades> | <decades> <digits> ;

Comment: thanks your input and i tried what you mentioned. 
public <greet> = [ <digits> ] [ <decades> ] [<numto44>];  sometime decades getting printed when i say digits. How to code when i want to say name , only the names which i mentioned only has to recognize. after that i will say digits.

Comment: Take a look at this http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/doc/sphinx4/edu/cmu/sphinx/jsgf/JSGFGrammar.html to learn how JSGF rules are composed. Note, that you can also add weights to your rules. In case of ambiguity the rule with the higher weight is favored.